# What is tag [roman] for?

Tags: discussion, tags

At the moment, History SE has tags [ancient-rome](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ancient-rome), [roman-empire](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roman-empire) and [roman-republic](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roman-republic). What exactly is tag [roman](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roman) for?

Using a single adjective as a tag name is not very descriptive, is it?

Comment: Especially since it's often used in conjunction with one of the others.